# Neglect all escape characters and code JAVA

Tags: java, ansi-escape

Situation:

- I've got a string created like so

  ```
  \033[32m\033[44mP"+characterID+"\033[0m"
  ```
- when the string is printed to console it prints out `P + characterID`
  in green like it should

Problem:

- I need to create a label with the `string P + characterID`
- But instead the text placed is `[32m[44mP"+characterID+"[0m`

What now:

- Given that i have several strings with different colors, regex and
  replace doesn't seem to work for all.
- is there anyway, i can neglect the escape codes and color when
  creating the text?

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about Swing's JLabel or AWT - you can't use ANSI escape codes as you did in console. Instead you have to set the foreground or background color for that JLabel. Something like this:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("P" + characterID);
label.setColor(Color.GREEN);
```

**EDIT:** If you already have "encoded" strings then you should come up with a regex that will find just the "real" data and ignore escape codes.
Assuming you only have `P`, `M` and `T` prefixes and the `characterID` is a decimal number the regex should like this:

```
String realData = "\\033[32m\\033[44mP111\\033[0m".replace("[^PMT]\\d+", "");
```

This should remove everything but the data you need.

Comment: thats what i wish to do, but i should have added that there are several string P + characterID or M + characterID or T + characterID etc. Thats why i was looking for a way to just strip out the escape codes leaving the result of type P(or M or T) + characterID rather than having to add a field in the super class hold a string of this kind P + characterID.